# Set the cursor in JavaScript for a long synchronous operation

Tags: javascript, html, cursor

I am trying to set a global page cursor (using `cursor: wait !important;` on `document.body`) at the beginning of a long-running *synchronous* XmlHttpRequest (synchronous sucks I know but let's not worry about that right now), however the browser (testing in Chrome) doesn't update the cursor until control is returned from the script, which doesn't happen until the end of the long-running operation.

It works great for asynchronous XmlHttpRequests (and therefore migrating the synchronous ones to be asynchronous is obviously one solution).

Is there any way to get the browser to refresh the cursor without breaking out of the current synchronous operation?

Comment: Put the request in a separate function, and call that function after a short delay.

Comment: That might be possible in some cases, but a lot of the logic right now is written under the assumption of it being synchronous.

Answer (score 3):

As Teemu commented above, you have to delay the execution of the function, even if by zero milliseconds (which will schedule it for the next tick of the event loop, giving the browser a chance to update the UI before it starts):

```
// change cursor
document.body.style.cursor = "wait !important";

// call long-running function from setTimeout
setTimeout(longRunningFunction, 0);
```

That's the only solution I know, but it may not work for you, since you state that "a lot of the logic right now is written under the assumption of it being synchronous", as you'll be effectively making it start asynchronously.

Comment: To follow up here, modern browsers choose NOT to re-render the DOM until the JavaScript execution thread has been idle for a few milliseconds. If you apply a new style or css class immediately before a long-running function, the DOM will not re-render. Also, a safer setTimeout() delay value is 20ms.